# How does machine learning handle the vast number of words in NLP application

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language

Disclaimer: I'm no expert in the field, this question could be axiomatically flawed.

When programming a very basic regression based machine learning algorithm one uses a number of variables; it seems to me that when applying this to natural language processing the number of variables would be so large that the training set would be unreasonable. I've heard that a good rule of thumb for training set size is 5 - 15 times the number of variables - even with a relatively simple application that's many thousands of words - many millions of 2 word 'n-grams'.

Overall question: How would one apply machine learning when one of the inputs is a body of text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are other techniques, but the simplest one is to start with dimensionality reduction - e.g. Principal Component Analysis. After reducing the dimensionality you can employ usual ML tools for doing classification, regression, etc.

Here are a few articles that may give you more information about the process

- Martins, C. A., Monard, M. C., & Matsubara, E. T. (2003). Reducing the dimensionality of bag-of-words text representation used by learning algorithms. [pdf](http://www.icmc.usp.br/~mcmonard/public/iastedce2003.pdf)
- Shafiei, M. et al (2007). Document representation and dimension reduction for text clustering. [pdf](https://web.cs.dal.ca/~eem/cvWeb/pubs/tdmm-2007-final.pdf)
- Penagarikano, M., Varona, A., Rodríguez, L. J., & Bordel, G. (2011). Dimensionality Reduction for Using High-Order n-Grams in SVM-Based Phonotactic Language Recognition. [pdf](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221484915_Dimensionality_Reduction_for_Using_High-Order_n-Grams_in_SVM-Based_Phonotactic_Language_Recognition)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Any time I get an answer with references it's always more helpful!